# ¿Cómo transformar una columna de un dataset en formato JSON a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, dataframe

Tengo un *dataset* que tiene una columna en formato JSON y deseo convertirla en un *DataFrame*. Los datos son más de 40 mil, pero un ejemplo de los datos en la columna es:

```json
{'id': 96871, 'name': 'Father of the Bride Collection', 'poster_path': '/nts4iOmNnq7GNicycMJ9pSAn204.jpg', 'backdrop_path': '/7qwE57OVZmMJChBpLEbJEmzUydk.jpg'}
{'id': 119050, 'name': 'Grumpy Old Men Collection', 'poster_path': '/nLvUdqgPgm3F85NMCii9gVFUcet.jpg', 'backdrop_path': '/hypTnLot2z8wpFS7qwsQHW1uV8u.jpg'}
{'id': 10194, 'name': 'Toy Story Collection', 'poster_path': '/7G9915LfUQ2lVfwMEEhDsn3kT4B.jpg', 'backdrop_path': '/9FBwqcd9IRruEDUrTdcaafOMKUq.jpg'}
```